# Summing up every second cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the situation I'm having in a Google spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

I need to sum up every second cell in the yellow line (look at the picture) not including those ones which are below the statement `FALSE` in the red line. Those statements are written in two merged cells if it has any importance in solving this problem. In this example, the right numbers should be: `4.00`, `4.00`, `8.00` with `16.00` as a final answer.

I did some research in various Excel forums and found out this line should do the trick for summing up every second cell in a single column beginning with `B3` cell:

```
= SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($B$3:$B$22) - ROW($B$3) + 1, 2) = 0, $B$3:B$22, 0))
```

I adjusted this to my situation (for the moment ignoring the fact about TRUE-FALSE check):

```
= SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($E$6:$N$6) - COLUMN($E$6) + 1, 2)=0, $E$6:N$6, 0))
```

Unfortunately, it is not working for me in a Google spreadsheet. Finally, I came up with formula which is working corectly for this purpose:

```
  = SUM(IF($E$2 = "TRUE", $F6, 0), IF($G$2 = "TRUE", $H6, 0), IF($I$2 = "TRUE", $J6, 0), IF($K$2 = "TRUE", $L6, 0), IF($M$2 = "TRUE", $N6, 0))
```

The problem is that constructing the formula this way is going to make it extremely long and way too inconvenient (as hundreds of columns are going to be added on the left)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, E2-F2, G2-H2, I2-J2, K2-L2, M2-N2 are merged cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easy to solve if you used a column to do the logic breakout.

For example, In column 7 put the following two formulas:

E7:

```
=if(E2="TRUE",E6,0)
```

F7:

```
=if(E2"TRUE",E7,0)
```

Then you can just SUM this row of tests.

Unfortunately Google Doc's formulas are not always as advanced as Excel's so sometimes you must do workarounds to make things possible.

That being said...
If you really want an All-In-One Formula solution for google docs... try this:

```
=SUMIF(E2:N2,"TRUE",E6:N6)+SUMIF(E2:N2,"TRUE",F6:N6)
```

The magic happens in the second SUMIF, Note that it starts with F6 thus offputting the sum-array by 1. To implement just change the letter "N" in the formula with your last column in the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Unfortunately those cells bellow are going to be used for the same reason as yellow marked line. More to add, the numbers under FALSE statement are also going to be summed up for another purpose. Due to that, trying to implement your suggested workaround would basically cause having two irrelevant rows under each "yellow" line which means 60 row table instead of 20, for example. Thanks again!

Comment: Your lastly suggested formula sums the whole line up, not every second cell. But I have tried to use only the last part: _SUMIF(E2:N2,"TRUE",F6:N6)_
It seems to work this way!

Comment: Oh, i misread your question. I thought you wanted to sum all of the yellow! 
The first half of my sumif was for the left yellows, the ssecond half was for the right of the yellows as you've already discovered!

Comment: Thank's a lot again! I am looking at the simplicity of this new approach, and you know what, that's not even a workaround, that's exact answer I was looking for!